# Has the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) been removed from Ruby in version 2.2?

Tags: ruby

Someone mentioned it had (been removed), but I haven't been able to find any reference to it either way on the web.

Can anyone point to some reliable documentation either way?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS) is the list of changes. I don't see it listed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It hasn't. Proving a negative can be tricky, although this would be a pretty massive change to not be mentioned in the release notes. It's also easy enough to see that the GIL related apis (rb_thread_blocking_function etc are still present)

In addition a [post to ruby-core](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/67516) recently asked what progress had been made on a GIL free ruby and the answer was "none"

Answer (score 4):

The GIL is still in place, perhaps you were thinking of the changes to garbage collection. Here are the changes since 2.1:

> - Incremental GC (presentation at RubyConf 2014: “Incremental GC for    Ruby interpreter”)
> - Symbol GC (presentation at RubyKaigi 2014)
> - configure –with-jemalloc Feature #9113 core libraries: Support
> - Unicode 7.0 #9092 New methods: Enumerable#slice_after #9071,
> - Enumerable#slice_when #9826 Float#next_float, Float#prev_float #9834
> - File.birthtime, File#birthtime #9647 String#unicode_normalize #10084
> - bundled libraries:
>
>   - Update Psych 2.0.8
>   - Update Rake 10.4.2
>   - Update RDoc 4.2.0
>   - Update RubyGems 2.4.5
>   - Update test-unit 3.0.8 (removed from repository but bundled in tarball)
>   - Update minitest 5.4.3 (removed from repository but bundled in tarball)
>   - Deprecate mathn
> - C API
>
>   - Remove deprecated APIs

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/12/25/ruby-2-2-0-released/